# How to get current locale of Eclipse from a plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, internationalization, eclipse-rcp, locale

The locale of Eclipse can be set at start up via `eclipse.ini` adding this line:

```
-Duser.language=<locale>
```

But how can I get the locale in an Eclipse RCP application (plugin)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same way as in every java application:

```
Locale.getDefault();
```

Have a look at "Using a Default Locale":
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/locale-140624.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen#using

There is also the LocaleProvider service, depending on your needs:
http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fosgi%2Fservice%2Flocalization%2FLocaleProvider.html

Answer (score 0):

To load the "-Duser.name=xxx" in a eclipse.ini file within a plugin product. 
Just use `System.getProperty("user.name")`. 
Hope this may help you.

Comment: It's strange, I started Eclipse in japanese using `-Duser.language=ja` but if I print `System.getProperty("user.language")` I always get `en`, regardless the workbench is in japanese.